# Why does git clone hang when calling from a shell script which SSH's to a remote server?

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh, bitbucket

I am writing a small app for those in the company who don't like command line and to help with productivity. The app runs a shell script which gets input from the user, uses it to SSH to a remote staging server and git clone the repo to that remote server. SSH keys are all good for the staging server and on Bitbucket. I can manually SSH into the server and git clone without any issue. I have also managed to get it to work going to a live server for initial setup. All other commands sent to the server are working.

The code used for this particular part is:

```
ssh $SUSER@$SHOST "git clone --depth 1 git@bitbucket.org:team/$SITEADDRESS.git --branch staging $CURRDIR"
```

I've also tried to run this manually from terminal with the following code:

```
ssh user@server "GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone -v --depth 1 git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git --branch staging /path/to/folder"
```

This is the output I get:

```
trace: built-in: git 'clone' '-v' '--depth' '1' 'git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git' '--branch' 'staging' '/path/to/folder'
Cloning into '/path/to/folder'...
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@bitbucket.org' 'git-upload-pack '\''team/repo.git'\'''
trace: run_command: '--shallow-file' '/path/to/folder/.git/shallow.lock' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 557 on ubuntu'
trace: exec: 'git' '--shallow-file' '/path/to/folder/.git/shallow.lock' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 557 on ubuntu'
trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 557 on ubuntu'
```

At this point it just hangs without errors instead of moving on to `remote: Counting objects: 4535, done.` and cloning the repo.

I've been trying to get this working for quite a few hours now and have been unable to find any info on similar problems. Using Git v1.9.1